# tag audio and ogg

Tags: linux, html, audio, html5-audio, ogg

I try to use tag audio. Convert mp3 to ogg use

```
ffmpeg -i "123.mp3" "1234.ogg"
```

Server response content-type for .ogg like video/ogg. 
I try content-type audio/ogg and application/ogg but it doesn't work too.
I think my file have got wrong format, because in player it works.
How to correct convert file from mp3 to ogg in linux console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try using the `file` command on the file to see what it says about the content?

Just out of curiosity.

I prefer to use the [oggenc](http://linux.die.net/man/1/oggenc) command myself . . I don't think there is 1 correct way to do it . . Like most things there are many ways to get there.

Comment: /music# file 123.ogg
123.ogg: Ogg data

Comment: Yep, oggenc is the official encoder.

Most linuxes have it in their package system (eg on ubuntu you can `apt-get install oggenc` etc . .)

It should be in the vorbis tools package on the xiph.org site.